# SASS include parent styles

Tags: sass

I am trying to find a way to include the parents styles within nested styles. In the code below, I want to include the width and box-sizing that are set on `.random-div` in the two nested styles too, so that `.random-div--large` would have `width`, `box-sizing` and `padding` all set.

```
.random-div {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    &--large {
        padding: 65px 45px;
    }

    &--small {
        padding: 25px 15px;
    }
}
```

I've tried extending the parent class within the nested ones but that includes all of the other nested styles too. Is there any way to just include the parent styles?

Comment: You could create a mixin containing the styles, which you then can include in both elements. I'm not sure if there is any other way to do this. You can also consider adding both the random-div and random-div--large classes to the same element (which is something I prefer, it keeps your CSS cleaner).

Comment: Why is there a `less` tag?

Comment: I don't have to tell you because you have been a member of SO long enough to know this. But still, please don't add Less tag if you are looking for Sass answers (and vice-versa) because that leads users to think that a Less answer is welcomed when it probably may not be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a placeholder and use that.

```
%random-div {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.random-div {
    @extend %random-div;
    &--large {
    @extend %random-div;
        padding: 65px 45px;
    }

    &--small {
    @extend %random-div;
        padding: 25px 15px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`@extend` rule](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend) without using a placeholder, just reference the parent class you want to extend:

```
.random-div {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  &--large {
    @extend .random-div;
    padding: 65px 45px;
  }

  &--small {
    @extend .random-div;
    padding: 25px 15px;
  }
}
```

This will compile to:

```
.random-div, .random-div--small, .random-div--large {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.random-div--large {
  padding: 65px 45px;
}
.random-div--small {
  padding: 25px 15px;
}
```

Note you can't use  the [parent selector (`&`)](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector) with the `@extend` rule, so this **won't work**:

```
.random-div {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  &--large {
    @extend &;
    padding: 65px 45px;
  }

  &--small {
    @extend &;
    padding: 25px 15px;
  }
}
```

Comment: How does this handle the child classes, as in the `--larger` will have itself nested in itself?

Comment: @SamWillis That's not how `@extend` works, it only takes into account the selector you are extending. Take a look at the output I have just included.

Answer (score 1):

with your bem methodology your div should have both identifier and modifier and should look like this

```
<div class="random-div random-div--large"></div>
```

so it will get all three styles.

Comment: We are tying to avoid having to add all the classes in the html, so that `random-div--large` would contain all of the styles of `random-div` as well as the extra ones that would make it large.