# SCSS use parent style for children (texts)

Tags: sass

I have next scss code:

```css
.btn {
    font-size: 24pt;
    color: red;

    &-small {
        font-size: 17pt;
    }

    &-meddium {
        font-size: 24pt;
    }

    &-big {
        font-size: 36pt;
    }
}
```

and i want that all my buttons (btn, btn-small, btn-meddium, btn-big) will have color RED.

P.S. I want realize it by only one class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SASS include parent styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35992578/sass-include-parent-styles)

Comment: @subarachnid yeah, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using SCSS, you can use `@mixin` and `@include`:

```
@mixin btn {
    color: red;
}

.btn {
     @include btn;
}

.btn-smaall {
    @include btn;
    font-size: 17pt;
}
```

And to to do that for the rest of the button classes you want to create.

Another way would be to addjust your selectors as such:

```css
.btn {
    font-size: 24pt;
    color: red;

    &.btn-small {
        font-size: 17pt;
    }

    &.btn-meddium {
        font-size: 24pt;
    }

    &.btn-big {
        font-size: 36pt;
    }
}
```

And then you can create a small button by adding the class `btn` and `btn-small` to a button. e.g. `<button class="btn btn-small>Test</button>`

Comment: sorry, but i wrote about few classes

Comment: My bad, added another solution, which will allow you to use one class only in the top of the post

Comment: @kitsoRik Added an example of a `@mixin` and how to use the `@include` keyword to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can define classes like this (my preference): `btn` `btn__small`

Then you can trigger it with scss like you wanted:

```
.btn {
    font-size: 24pt;
    color: red;

    &__small {
        font-size: 17pt;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, but i wrote about few classes